# Can Nant be used to deploy to different servers?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, nant, release-management

Can Nant be used to deploy an application to a different set of servers based on some type of property/parameter?

What I need NANT to do:
An environment is made up of 1 or more servers.
We have multiple environments (dev, qa, prod).
The package contains multiple web-site projects.

When NANT is asked to build for DEV, it needs to build the projects and setup the web.config up correctly to work in the DEV environment (connection strings, etc). In addition each web-site project needs to be deployed to the correct server for that environment.

In addition, can NANT be used to build all my projects once and then deploy it multiple times (deploy to Dev, QA, Prod environments?) (ie, the build and deploy are done at different times and once a build has been created, the deploy could be run on that build package multiple times)

Comment: Found this extremely helpful tutorial on using Nant to deploy to multiple environments: http://hallertech.com/nant/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my answer here for Configuration Management: [Should I have multiple build.xml files for one project (dev,staging,production)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986954/should-i-have-multiple-build-xml-files-for-one-project-dev-staging-production/6987091#6987091)

Basically you need `environment configs` for DEV, QA, PREPROD, PROD etc, specify the environment you want to deploy during deploy ( say from command line through `-D:environment=DEV` ) which will use the appropriate config and deploy.

`Build once, deploy everywhere` is the general approach you should follow. Build and deploy should be separate targets. Use a CI tool if needed ( like Jenkins, TeamCity) to build the application. Expose the build application ( zip, tar, war etc) as Artifacts. In the deploy target, download the necessary artifact and do the deploy.

Comment: I get the "build once, deploy everywhere" and I also understand how one can use separate environment configs where the environment is provided from the command line. What I dont understand is how do I setup the build file to "build once"? Should I have 2 separate Nant projects: 1. for the build, 2: for the deployment?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar NAnt solution in place and this is what works well form me. In the same build file, I define different targets for compiling and setting up the different config files for each environment. My deployment target takes uses 3 parameters: copy source, copy destination, config file.

The files are copied from source to destination. Then the specified config file (Web.config.dev, Web.config.qa, Web.config.production) are copied to the destination and renamed to Web.config.